# Как открыть файл в программе на Python двойным кликом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Написал приложение на Python, которое работает с файлами собственного расширения (*.tjp)
В системе прописаны файловые ассоциации.
При двойном клике по файлу *.tjp моя программа запускается, но как ей сообщить, что она должна сразу открыть этот файл?

Программа упакована в EXE, работает в графическом интерфейсе без консоли.

Comment: ```
from os import system as cmd
cmd("ПУТЬ К ВАШЕМУ ФАЙЛУ")
```

Comment: @dudha369
А каким образом передать путь к файлу, если мы не знаем изначально какой файл будет открывать пользователь? Программа упакована в EXE, работает в графическом интерфейсе без консоли (добавлю это уточнение в вопрос).

Comment: @Павел путь к кликнутому файлу передаётся в аргументах командной строки (`sys.argv`)

Comment: В своей программе переданный путь ищите в списке sys.argv по индексу 1. Только нужно добавить проверку, что `len(sys.argv) > 1`. Дальше на нужном файле правой кнопкой -> открыть с помощью -> указываете свой экзешник.